# How can I fix android tablet's width and height

Tags: android, fragment, tablet

I am making android application in tablet using fragments so that I arranged 8 buttons vertically in 10.1 tablet it is showing fine but in 7.1 tablet only 5 icons it is showing.
So How can I manage height and width properly in all tablets ... please help

Answer (score 1):

Remember to write different xml layouts (with same name) and place to different folders: layout-large, layout-normal, layout-small and layout-xlarge. Same is with *drawables* (different size images) and *values* (different type padding and other values). These folders are for different phone/tablet types with various resolution and screen size. If you do it, then you can easily manage layout for small device and not touch big screen devices. Device is picking xml file automatically so it's good practice to place xml files in different folders for various phones.

More information you can find in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use different layout for different screen sizes. You can also add different buttons and other drawable also. Please see the link

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write different xml layouts using different folders:
For example:

```
res/layout
res/layout-sw600dp    //used by  7''
res/layout-sw720dp    //used by 10''
```

Also you can use the same layout with the same component but with different dimensions.
You can use `@dimen/my_dimen` notation, and then put your my_dimen in different folders like:

```
res/values/dimens.xml
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
```

and so on..

Official doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html